# Matplotlib print nothing when 'nan' with strings

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a discontinuous plot that prints nothing when the variable is 'nan'. Unfortunately, because the y axis of this plot reports string values, when a 'nan' occurs, the plot just creates a 'nan' tick on the y axis.

As an example:

[image]

I would like that the blue plot displays nothing when 'nan' occurs, instead of considering nan as a string.

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:

As a minimal example, lets suppose I wrote:

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
y = ['Stairs',np.nan, 'Sitting', np.nan, 'Stairs','Falling','Falling','Standing',np.nan]
plt.plot(x,y)
```

And it gives me the following result:

[image]

I would like the nan not to display on the plot. Is it possible?

Comment: Offering a different perspective here: `nan` means *not a number*. But that's irrelevant, because you're plotting strings. You would need *not a string* (nas), which doesn't exist. Of course you can encode your strings into numbers (where `numpy.unique` might become handy) and plotting those numbers allows to use `nan` as usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could plot using integer indices, and then label the ticks accordingly:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
y = ['Stairs',np.nan, 'Sitting', np.nan, 'Stairs','Falling','Falling','Standing',np.nan]
y_ticks = ['Stairs', 'Sitting', 'Falling', 'Standing']
y_int = [np.nan if elem is np.nan else y_ticks.index(elem) for elem in y]
plt.plot(x, y_int, '.-')
plt.yticks(range(len(y_ticks)), y_ticks)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it somehow like this:

```
y_List = ['sss', NaN, 'ddd', ....]
y_List_new = []
for i in y_List:
    if i != NaN:
        y_List_new.append(i)
```

and then just plot y_List_new :)
edit: of course I forgot, you need to do this for the first list (x values) too, otherwise you would have too much values

Comment: I had a string which I replaced with np.nan, which got interpreted as the string 'nan'. If i substitute with strings such as 'NaN', 'NAN', etc... it doesn't work anyway

Comment: It should work if you do `if str(i).lower() != "nan"`

Comment: Why not `isnan`?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: if you are using the categorical plotting capabilities of matplotlib (see the [gallery example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/categorical_variables.html)), then it is not possible to have a discontinuous plot.  That code will convert your nan into a string, as you have observed.  I would probably use 'None' to indicate the missing values, and plot the parts in chunks, if I were you:

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
y = ['Stairs', None, 'Sitting', None, 'Stairs', 'Falling', 'Falling', 'Standing', None]
curr_x = []
curr_y = []
for xval, yval in zip(x, y):
    if yval is None:
        if curr_x:
            ax.plot(curr_x, curr_y, "-bo")
            curr_x = []
            curr_y = []
    else:
        curr_x.append(xval)
        curr_y.append(yval)
ax.plot(curr_x, curr_y, "-bo")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I supposed that the categorical plot was the issue, but I didn't think of such a trick to overcome the problem!